# Url rewriting - how to handle links

Tags: php

I would like to run different php code depending on the first part of the url and I would also like to be able to handle the links accordingly.

My code is being designed to serve a different skinned website depending on the url.

These are some example urls

```
www.example.com/dev/site_number_one
www.example.com/dev/another_random_site
www.example.com/dev/third_random_name
```

The php files, etc are in the dev folder. However there are no folders named site_numer_one, another_random_site. I want to have a switch statement in my php code where I look at what the folder name is eg site_number_one, and I run a different functions depending on what the name is. **I have semi-achieved this** with the following code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This sends any urls which dont map to an existing file to the index. And I use the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to parse the folder string etc.

**My two problems**

1. I have pages like www.example.com/dev/contact_us, which is an actual file. But the problem is if a user goes to www.example.com/dev/site_number_one/contact_us, the page will not be found because there is no site_number_one folder.
2. Links on pages that I echo out don't have the imaginary file name preceding them etc Do I have to sort this out myself for every link?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the problem with 1. is. As for 2.: Yes, you need to make your links the way you want them to look. mod_rewrite is only helping you resolve those into executable files, it can't help you with creating them.

Comment: Do you know how to handle things so that when the user goes to www.example.com/dev/site_number_one/contact_us, they will be shown the contact us page... I want to be able to pass the string 'site_number_one' to a function that generates the contact_us page. Can you give a simple example how to achieve this in lavarel or in a router like klein?

Comment: Depends on the exact router in question, but you'd simply create a route like `/dev/:id/contact_us` and point it to a controller, which gets passed the `:id` part as variable.